# WCF return double in JSON format and limit numbers after coma

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to return double value in json format and limit count of numbers after coma to 6.

Ex: 12.310203

When number is 12.310203123123

I dont want to convert to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.Round(12.310203123123, 6, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

You can change the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero also. Feel free to view documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)

You can also ignore that overload, and simply do:
`Math.Round(12.310203123123, 6)` if you dont care about the rounding.

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsoft JSON Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx?ppud=4) is easy and does a great job of serializing to JSON.  I'm guessing you already know about that and that you want something else.  I sometimes have custom JSON serialization needs - for example a string that needs to be serialized without quotes so that in JavaScript it's parsed as an object.  The MS serializer didn't do that.

So for cases like this I've used [James Newton King's (excellent) JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), which allows for custom serialization handlers.

Using JSON.NET you do this...

[DefaultValue(null), JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MyCustomJSON"), JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomJsonConverter))]
        public string MyCustomJSON { get; set; }

...and...

public class MyCustomJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

```
    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value as string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 12.310203123123;
double round = Math.Round(d, 6);
```